# How can I use control-A character as csvDelimiter in AWS-DMS Target S3 Endpoint?

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, delimiter, aws-dms

I am extracting the data from Aurora to S3 using AWS DMS, and would like to use csvDelimiter of my choice, which is ^A (i.e. control-A, octal representation \001) while loading data to S3. How do I do that?. By default when S3 is used as target for DMS, it uses "," as default delimiter

`compressionType=NONE;csvDelimiter=,;csvRowDelimiter=\n;`

But I want to use something as below
`compressionType=NONE;csvDelimiter='\001';csvRowDelimiter=\n;`

But it prints the delimiter as a text in the output:
`I'\001'12345'\001'Abc'`

I am using AWS DMS Console to set the Target Endpoint
I tried below delimiters but did not work:

`\\001`
`\u0001`
`'\u0001'`
`\u01`
`\001`

Actual Result:
`I'\001'12345'\001'Abc'`
Expected Result:
`I^A12345^AAbc`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to resolve this:

I used aws command line to set this delimiter in my target s3 endpoint.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/setup-awscli.html

aws cli command:

```
aws dms modify-endpoint --endpoint-arn arn:aws:dms:us-west-2:000001111222:endpoint:OXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX4 --endpoint-identifier dms-ep-tgt-s3-abc --endpoint-type target --engine-name s3 --extra-connection-attributes "bucketFolder=data/folderx;bucketname=bkt-xyz;CsvRowDelimiter=^D;CompressionType=NONE;CsvDelimiter=^A;" --service-access-role-arn arn:aws:iam::000001111222:role/XYZ-Datalake-DMS-Role --s3-settings ServiceAccessRoleArn=arn:aws:iam::000001111222:role/XYZ-Datalake-DMS-Role,BucketName=bkt-xyz,CompressionType=NONE
```

Output:

```
{
"Endpoint": {
    "Status": "active", 
    "S3Settings": {
        "CompressionType": "NONE", 
        "EnableStatistics": true, 
        "BucketFolder": "data/folderx", 
        "CsvRowDelimiter": "\u0004", 
        "CsvDelimiter": "\u0001", 
        "ServiceAccessRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::000001111222:role/XYZ-Datalake-DMS-Role", 
        "BucketName": "bkt-xyz"
    }, 
    "EndpointType": "TARGET", 
    "ServiceAccessRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::000001111222:role/XYZ-Datalake-DMS-Role", 
    "SslMode": "none", 
    "EndpointArn": "arn:aws:dms:us-west-2:000001111222:endpoint:OXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX4", 
    "ExtraConnectionAttributes": "bucketFolder=data/folderx;bucketname=bkt-xyz;CompressionType=NONE;CsvDelimiter=\u0001;CsvRowDelimiter=\u0004;", 
    "EngineDisplayName": "Amazon S3", 
    "EngineName": "s3", 
    "EndpointIdentifier": "dms-ep-tgt-s3-abc"
}
```

}

Note: After you run the aws cli command, the DMS console will not show you the delimiter in the endpoint, (not visible as it is a special character). But once you run the task it appears in the data in your s3 files.